# Create new Labels in Gmail App

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

Gmail App in my Android device shows correctly all the labels that I created using Gmail through web interface.

**Can I create new labels in Gmail on Android device using Gmail App?**

Also, ideally, once I create these new labels in Gmail App, I obviously should be seeing the same in Web Interface of Gmail too (Sync!!).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't post an answer but I actually developed an app a while back that does this exactly https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applay.glabels

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of current writing, it seems that it's (still) impossible to create a new label in Android Gmail app. From [Google Gmail official support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1),

> #### Create a label
>
> 1. On a computer, open [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/). You can't create labels from the Gmail app.
> 2. On the left, click **More**.
> 3. Click **Create new label**.
> 4. Name your label.
> 5. Click **Create**.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

Answer (score 8):

If [Inbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox) App is installed on the device and has access to Gmail ID, then from `Inbox` App, it is possible to create a Gmail Label, and the same will be SYNC to Gmail App.

There is an option in `Inbox` App's Navigation drawer (sliding menu) to create new Gmail Labels.

Not sure why the same is not made available in the official Gmail App itself, because the app is [developed by the Gmail Team only.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox)

Comment: Too bad they got rid of Inbox.

Answer (score 3):

How I found I could create a new label on Android:

- Open Android Chrome.
- Invoke Gmail within Chrome (via that 3x3 grid selector), which opens the Mobile version of Gmail.
- Open an email & scroll to the bottom and you'll see:
  "View Gmail in: Mobile | Older version | Desktop"
- Click on "Desktop", which will open the desktop version of Gmail where you can create a folder as you would on your laptop.
- Close all Android apps. Then when you reopen the Gmail app, you will see the newly created folder.

Why oh why cannot such a rich company with so much talent put something as basic as label creation in their mobile app. Geez! :(

Comment: Yes! This works. If you choose "Desktop site" from the Chrome menu while on the Gmail site it still appears in mobile mode. You have to use the link at the bottom of the email view.